# What network conditions are pagespeed insights using for Desktop and Mobile profiles?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to get Lighthouse to provide results similar to what we get from Pagespeed Insights, but the numbers are way off. Currently looking at score and ttfb. This is being run from various locations on the planet, and we are looking to get the latency impact factored in in a reasonable way, as distance to origin matters as not all content in our case can be cached at the edge.

In the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about) it states:

*"Currently, Lighthouse simulates a page load on a mid-tier device (Moto G4) on a mobile network."*

If this is the Mobile profile, what is then the best match for the Desktop profile? or is the difference defined in viewport size too?

Answer (score 2):

Desktop profile is with no throttling on CPU and Connection. So I would expect your browser based audit to be similar to the PSI desktop tab (assuming you have a decent connection).

For Mobile view it uses a 4x slowdown on CPU (this is the bit most people forget about when setting throttling manually) to simulate a mid-tier device and [throttling of 150ms latency and 1.6Mbps down / 750 Kbps up.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md)

Yet again the desktop should be similar to the PSI results if you use the 'simulated' slowdown setting, if you use 'applied' it will nearly always score lower (and is more accurate for real world).

For viewport - desktop is 1920 x 1080 (virtually rendered via headless browser on PSI so you do get some minor differences) and mobile is 412 x 732 now (same on PSI as audits tab).

If you are trying to get latency factored in a reasonable way you should just ping some servers in other countries and add that to your latency locally. i.e. if you have a 15ms ping to your server and you ping a server in Australia and get 185ms ping then add the difference (185-15 = 170) to all of your latency settings (so mobile would be 320ms with the above example).

Comment: Thanks. Actually i get 100 in score from my local machine without throttling and 58 using the mobile throttle. On PSI they are 85/55. That my local machine, a laptop over wif, connected to the internet using ADSL, is outperforming a Google datacenter running PSI is not what I would expect :)  My assumption is that Desktop score on PSI is somehow limited by network shaping too, and this is what i would like to match.  Measuring the latency and adding it as a parameter makes sense, so good idea.

Comment: Actually just adding the latency might not be a good recipe. We would have certain assets on the page fetch from edge (e.g. in Australia) and thereby with low latency, and other assets such as the main document being fetched from origin with high latency. The reality would be a mix of high and low latency. The simulated would be all the same latencies. Any thoughts on how to deal with that?

Comment: At that point I would imagine you would be using puppeteer to set the latency for each origin, it isn't something you can do out of the box as far as I am aware. The only thing I could suggest as a workaround is to deliberately slow down your server by a certain amount on all requests to simulate latency to the origin.

Comment: Also I should add that although it isn't stated anywhere I think the PSI servers are US based and not on a CDN as you would expect. This is just my observation based on TTFB on a nearly blank page (from UK) being about 50ms slower so I could be wrong.